# TextBox isn't showing more then one file

Tags: visual-studio

```
    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "TEXT FILE | *.xml"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox2.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If

End Sub
```

TextBox isn't showing more then one file, I have allowed multiselect in OpenFileDialog and multiline in TextBox is activated as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Filenames` property. Since it's an array you will need to join the individual values together to put it into a text box.

```
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    TextBox2.Text = String.Join(",", OpenFileDialog1.FileNames)
End If
```